# Image Based Visual Servoing algorithm in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, vision, control-theory

I was trying to implement the IBVS algorithm (the one explained in the Introduction [here](http://www.irisa.fr/lagadic/visp/documentation/visp-2.10.0/tutorial-ibvs.html)) in MATLAB myself, but I am facing the following problem : The algorithm seems to work only for the cases that the camera does not have to change its orientation in respect to the world frame.For example, if I just try to make one vertex of the initial (almost) square go closer to its opposite vertex, the algorithm does not work, as can be seen in the following image

[image]

The red x are the desired projections, the blue circles are the initial ones and the green ones are the ones I get from my algorithm.

Also the errors are not exponentially dereasing as they should.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I am attaching my MATLAB code which is fully runable. If anyone could take a look, I would be really grateful. I took out the code that was performing the plotting. I hope it is more readable now. Visual servoing has to be performed with at least 4 target points, because else the problem has no unique solution. If you are willing to help, I would suggest you take a look at the `calc_Rotation_matrix()` function to check that the rotation matrix is properly calculated, then verify that the line `ds = vc;` in `euler_ode` is correct. The camera orientation is expressed in Euler angles according to [this](http://www.coppeliarobotics.com/helpFiles/en/eulerAngles.htm) convention. Finally, one could check if the interaction matrix `L` is properly calculated.

```
function VisualServo()

    global A3D B3D C3D D3D A B C D Ad Bd Cd Dd

    %coordinates of the 4 points wrt camera frame
    A3D = [-0.2633;0.27547;0.8956];
    B3D = [0.2863;-0.2749;0.8937];
    C3D = [-0.2637;-0.2746;0.8977];
    D3D = [0.2866;0.2751;0.8916];

    %initial projections (computed here only to show their relation with the desired ones) 
    A=A3D(1:2)/A3D(3);
    B=B3D(1:2)/B3D(3);
    C=C3D(1:2)/C3D(3);
    D=D3D(1:2)/D3D(3);

    %initial camera position and orientation
    %orientation is expressed in Euler angles (X-Y-Z around the inertial frame
    %of reference)
    cam=[0;0;0;0;0;0];

    %desired projections
    Ad=A+[0.1;0];
    Bd=B;
    Cd=C+[0.1;0];
    Dd=D;

    t0 = 0;
    tf = 50;

    s0 = cam;

    %time step
    dt=0.01;
    t = euler_ode(t0, tf, dt, s0);

end


function ts = euler_ode(t0,tf,dt,s0)

    global A3D B3D C3D D3D Ad Bd Cd Dd 

    s = s0;
    ts=[];
    for t=t0:dt:tf
        ts(end+1)=t;
        cam = s;

        % rotation matrix R_WCS_CCS
        R = calc_Rotation_matrix(cam(4),cam(5),cam(6));
        r = cam(1:3);

        % 3D coordinates of the 4 points wrt the NEW camera frame
        A3D_cam = R'*(A3D-r);
        B3D_cam = R'*(B3D-r);
        C3D_cam = R'*(C3D-r);
        D3D_cam = R'*(D3D-r);

        % NEW projections
        A=A3D_cam(1:2)/A3D_cam(3);
        B=B3D_cam(1:2)/B3D_cam(3);
        C=C3D_cam(1:2)/C3D_cam(3);
        D=D3D_cam(1:2)/D3D_cam(3);


        % computing the L matrices
        L1 = L_matrix(A(1),A(2),A3D_cam(3));
        L2 = L_matrix(B(1),B(2),B3D_cam(3));
        L3 = L_matrix(C(1),C(2),C3D_cam(3));
        L4 = L_matrix(D(1),D(2),D3D_cam(3));
        L = [L1;L2;L3;L4];


        %updating the projection errors
        e = [A-Ad;B-Bd;C-Cd;D-Dd];

        %compute camera velocity
        vc = -0.5*pinv(L)*e;

        %change of the camera position and orientation
        ds = vc;

        %update camera position and orientation
        s = s + ds*dt;


    end  
    ts(end+1)=tf+dt;
end

function R = calc_Rotation_matrix(theta_x, theta_y, theta_z)

    Rx = [1 0 0; 0 cos(theta_x) -sin(theta_x); 0 sin(theta_x) cos(theta_x)];
    Ry = [cos(theta_y) 0 sin(theta_y); 0 1 0; -sin(theta_y) 0 cos(theta_y)];
    Rz = [cos(theta_z) -sin(theta_z) 0; sin(theta_z) cos(theta_z) 0; 0 0 1];

    R = Rx*Ry*Rz;

end

function L = L_matrix(x,y,z)

    L = [-1/z,0,x/z,x*y,-(1+x^2),y;
       0,-1/z,y/z,1+y^2,-x*y,-x];
end
```

Cases that work:

```
Ad=2*A;
Bd=2*B;
Cd=2*C;
Dd=2*D;

Ad=A+1;
Bd=B+1;
Cd=C+1;
Dd=D+1;

Ad=2*A+1;
Bd=2*B+1;
Cd=2*C+1;
Dd=2*D+1;
```

Cases that do NOT work:
Rotation by 90 degrees and zoom out (zoom out alone works, but I am doing it here for better visualization)

```
Ad=2*D;
Bd=2*C;
Cd=2*A;
Dd=2*B;
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are your 2D points not re-projected properly? Are you getting errors? Is your interaction matrix not recalculated properly?

Comment: @beaker I added some images that show the problem. The code is also fully runable, so you can run and check if you like.

Comment: So, to move the camera with respect to the world frame, you're just adding  some offset to 2 of the 4 points?

Comment: @beaker I don't think so... Initially, the camera position and orientation wrt the world frame is [0,0,0,0,0,0]. Then I update the camera position and orientation inside the function euler_ode according to the control law vc = -0.5*pinv(L)*e;

Comment: Sorry, I can't run this code in Octave, which is all I have at hand right now, and without some indication as to where it's going wrong, well I'm just too lazy to weed through it all. My previous question was because your definition of `A2`, `B2`, `C2` and `D2` (why soooo many variables?) looks a bit suspect to me for a rigid-body transformation.

Comment: @beaker First of all, thank you for your time! As a last resort, I have added some more explanations and another graph of a case that does not work. In general, whenever the camera has to rotate in order to achieve the control goal, the algorithm fails. So, I am suspecting that I am not performing correctly the transformation of the 3D points to the camera frame. If any of that rings a bell to you, please let me know.

Comment: Your case that does not work looks the same as the first case that does work...

Comment: @beaker Well, it just proves that even when only a rotation around the z axis is needed, there is a problem.

Comment: Oh. I just had a thought looking at your last plot. You don't change the scaling on the camera velocity as you get closer. It's quite possible that you're overshooting the target each timestep.

Comment: @beaker How am I supposed to scale it?

Comment: Change the `0.5` to something smaller?

Comment: @beaker No, unfortunately this does not change anything..

Comment: That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code further until no code can be removed while still running into the problem?

Comment: @IKavanagh Much of the code is for the plots, so one does not have to check that. The parts that really compute something are very small I think

Comment: @Controller Then you should post only that code. Stack Overflow is based heavily around [mcve]'s. The people you are asking for help are busy and if you want a quick answer you should provide only the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the problem. See [ask].

Comment: @IKavanagh I shortened the code. thanks for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the way you move the camera from the resulting visual servoing velocity. Rather than

```
cam = cam + vc*dt;
```

you should compute the new camera position using the exponential map

```
cam = cam*expm(vc*dt)
```